# cannot open output file a.out: Permission denied, on a simple compilation

Tags: gcc, permissions

I wrote some code in vim and whenever I try to run the code it shows this:

```
coolmego@coolmego-PC:~/coolmego/cprograms$ gcc dfs8puzz.c 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file a.out: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
coolmego@coolmego-PC:~/coolmego/cprograms$ ./a.out
bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?

Comment: yaa..but when i use sudo command it works properly...although i changed the permission to all read,write an execute mode..by "chmod 777 filename"...but its not working within the directory specified on which it is actually saved...

Comment: What does `ls -ld ~/coolmego/cprograms` tell you?

Comment: @ Dennis Williamson : it shows something like this "drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 2011-03-15 19:37 /home/coolmego/coolmego/cprograms/"

Comment: You need to do `sudo chown cmego:cmego . *`

Answer (score 8):

Move to a directory where you are allowed to write.

Comment: yaa..but when i use sudo command it works properly...although i changed the permission to all read,write an execute mode..by "chmod 777 filename"...but its not working within the directory specified on which it is actually saved...

Answer (score 4):

This is because if you only have write permissions, but you are not the owner the directory.

1. Check your user name:

   ```
   whoami
   ```
2. Make yourself the owner of the directory and its contents:

   ```
    sudo chown -R "$USER:" /path/to/the/directory
   ```
3. Set read/write/execute permission

   ```
   chmod -R 700 /path/to/the/directory
   ```

refer https://askubuntu.com/questions/466605/cannot-open-output-file-permission-denied

Answer (score 0):

When you run sudo, you are actually running the commands as root user.  Possibly you ended up messing up the permissions so that root owns the files.  Thus when you run sudo, it just works (root can write in those directories). You need coolmego to own those files.  For example:

```
sudo chown coolmego /home/coolmego/coolmego/cprograms/
chmod 700 /home/coolmego/coolmego/cprograms/
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove option user in /etc/fstab. Anything with user in the fstab is automatically mounted noexec unless exec is explicitly given in the fstab.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving read write permission to the directory in which you are targeting to get the output. In case you are using a personal system you can do "sudo chmod 777 "

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem, after 1 hour i found out it was my Antivirus, i shut that down and everything worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

try `chmod -R 777 ~/coolmego/cprograms`

Comment: You should avoid this. You will make all your file executable, even your c code files. It can be a pain to revert this command if you have many files in this subdirectory.

Comment: Not a good idea, and wouldn't work anyway. The problem isn't the permissions, it's the ownership.